# SQL View from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a VIEW from one databse to another, they are both on the same SQL server.

```
CREATE VIEW mdl_role_assignments
AS
SELECT *
FROM the-db.mdl_role_assignments
```

Any ideas as to why i cant get this working.
I think its the hyphen in 'the-db', but i need to use this the db is already used.
(Was named by someone else, i would use underscore)

ERROR:
**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-db.mdl_role_assignments' at line 4**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try square brackets to reference complicated names in SQL e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW mdl_role_assignments
AS
SELECT *
FROM [the-db].mdl_role_assignments;
```

or backticks

```
CREATE VIEW mdl_role_assignments
AS
SELECT *
FROM `the-db`.`mdl_role_assignments`;
```

Comment: +1 - I think it's only backticks in MySQL; square brackets are MSSQL.

Comment: Brilliant backticks worked great! Dont know why i didn't try that. Put it down to pre brew.

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes - I believe you are right - worth knowing for any MSSQL work though :D